# radio button to enable number type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to enable a number type box when a (Qty)radio button is clicked.And disable when (rate) radio button is clicked.

**my view**

```
 <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="quantity" value="yes" id="rad1" onclick="radio()"/>PRN
    <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="quantity" value="no" id="rad2"  onclick="radio()" />Qty
     <input type="number" name="someid" id="textfield" disabled/>
```

**my javascript**

```
 $(".radioBtn").click(function radio() {
            $("#textfield").attr("disabled", true);
            if ($("input[name=quantity]:checked").val() == "yes") {
                $("#textfield").removeattr("disabled");
            }

    });
```

my link to connect view and js

Comment: Other than several errors, using both inline and jQuery event handlers etc. what exactly is the question here ?

Comment: my link to connect view and js <script src="~/Scripts/radio.js"></script>

Comment: I am not able to disable textbox when radio button is clicked

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, but I'm guessing something like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/8yb5bjp7/

Comment: exactly right!!

Comment: now where should i keep my javascript in view or as a javascript file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work on your end but seems good here. Just change removeattr to removeAttr

```
$("#textfield").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Also make sure you're including JQuery in your site.
For a better insight into why something might not be working, press F12 to open the console in a browser. This will show any errors.